# react route switch redirects to my / path

Tags: reactjs, router

Im using these files to make  /contact and /apropos pages in react.
But when I click the link to these or paste the url in the browser, in the console i see the same requests is done that when i go to / page

Here is the code:

index.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"; 
import App from "./components/App";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import { Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BlogPage } from "./BlogPage";
import { PostPage } from "./PostPage";
import {Contact} from "./Contact";
import {About} from "./About";
function App() { return (
<Switch>
    <Route path="/post/:id([\d]+)" component={PostPage}/>
    <Route path="/tag/:tag/:page([\d]+)?" component={BlogPage}/>
    <Route path="/:page([\d]+)?" component={BlogPage}/>
    <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
    <Route exact path="/apropos" component={About}/>
    <Route path="*"
            component={() => (
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <h1>404</h1>
                    </Row>
                </Container> )}
    />
</Switch>
); }
export default App;
```

Am I missing something?

THank you

Comment: I guess react check routes 1 by 1 to find a matching path. What if you try to put these 2 Routes higher in the list (/contact and /apropos)

Comment: are you sure you have the same routes in the links URL?

Comment: I ve figured out an answer:  i ve added exact to all my urls. 
But with more recent version of router they removed "exact"

Comment: then you will need to update your router version I think and follow the new syntax for building your routes